# Convert the following to polar form - don't understand solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to convert the following equations to polar form. I understand a and b, and I have answers shown for c, d, and e, but I don't quite understand their solutions.

Why is θ subtracted from 2pi for c and pi for d?

Also where did the pi/2 come from for e?

[image]

Thanks so much if someone could help explain!

Comment: Think about which quadrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will follow the standard procedure for the third question.

Step 1: Find $\theta$.

$3-4i$ is in the fourth quadrant (draw the real and imaginary axis on the complex plane to see this).

$\tan(\theta)=\frac{b}{a}=\frac{-4}{3}$

Thus, $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{-4}{3})=-0.9273$ which is equivalent to $\theta=2\pi - \arctan(\frac{4}{3})$.

Step 2: Find modulus $|z|$.

$r=|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=\sqrt{25}=5$

Step 3: Write out $z$ in polar form.

$z=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))=5(\cos(-0.9273)+i\sin(-0.9273))$ which is equivalent to $z=5cis(2\pi - \arctan(\frac{4}{3}))$.

Note: $cis(\theta) = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$. So,

\begin{align}
z&=5cis(2\pi - \arctan(\frac{4}{3}))\\
&=5cis(\theta)\\&=5(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))\\&=5(\cos(-0.9273)+i\sin(-0.9273))
\end{align}

The same strategy will work for the fourth and fifth question. Draw out the angle in the complex plane. The fourth question is in the second quadrant while the fifth question is on the positive imaginary axis.